# How do you read lines from all files in a directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have two files in a directory.  I'd like to read the lines from each of the files.  Unfortunately when I try to do so with the following code, there is no output.

```
from pathlib import Path 

p = Path('tmp')
for file in p.iterdir():
   print(file.name)
```

functions.py
test.txt

```
for file in p.iterdir():
    f = open(file, 'r')
    f.readlines()
```

Comment: lines = f.readlines()

Comment: There's no output because you're not outputting anything. Did you mean `print(f.readlines())`?

Comment: BTW, best practice for opening files is a with-statement: `with open(file) as f: ...`

Comment: Side-note: You rarely want to actually call `.readlines()`; usually, you just iterate the lines and process them as you go (`for line in f: print(line)`), and avoid slurping the whole file into memory. When you do need the whole file in memory, you frequently need it in some form other than a raw `list`, and avoiding `.readlines()` in favor of `sorted(f)`, `set(f)`, etc., or a loop that builds the data structure line by line (avoiding duplication or coalescing values in some other manner) rather than making a temporary `list` first, then building a new structure from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading all the lines from the file, but you're not outputting them. If you want to print the lines to standard output, you need to use `print()` as you did in your first example.

You can also write this somewhat more elegantly using contexts and more iterators:

```py
from pathlib import Path 

file = Path('test.txt')
with file.open() as open_file:
    for line in open_file:
        print(line, end="")
```

test.txt:

```
Spam
Spam
Spam
Wonderful
Spam!
Spamity
Spam
```

Result:

```
Spam
Spam
Spam
Wonderful
Spam!
Spamity
Spam
```

Using a context for opening the file (`with file.open()`) means you inherently set up closing the file, and the iterator for the lines (`for line in open_file`) means you're not loading the whole file at once (an important consideration with larger files).

Setting `end=""` in `print()` is optional depending on how your source files are structured, as you might otherwise end up printing extra blank lines in your output.

Comment: Note that using `print(line, end="")` is equivalent to just doing `sys.stdout.write(line)`; given that, if you just want to copy all the lines from input to `sys.stdout`, you could replace `for line in open_file: print(line, end="")` with just `sys.stdout.writelines(open_file)`; `open_file` is an iterable of strings, and `writelines` writes from an iterable of strings (lazily; this won't slurp the whole input into memory, it'll just read and write each line as it goes).

Answer (score 2):

You could use [**`fileinput`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):

```
import os
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(os.listdir('.')):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should print data like this from text.py

```
count = 1
f = open(file, 'r')
Lines = f.readlines()
for line in Lines:
    count += 1
    print("Line {}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

Output will look like:

```
Line 1: ...
Line 2: ...
Line 3: ...
```

you can see reading line example here - [Line reading](https://mindmajix.com/community/77795/python-read-file-line-by-line)

Comment: There are a lot of improvements you could make here: 1) Best practice for opening files is a `with` statement. 2) *UpperCamelCase* variable names (`Lines`) should be reserved for classes. 3) Don't bother with `f.readlines()` when you could iterate over `f` directly. 4) `enumerate(start=1)` instead of counting manually. 5) f-strings are simpler, but that's nbd. `with open(file) as f: for count, line in enumerate(lines, 1): print(f"Line {count}: {line.strip()}")`